# Select rows based on one column value exists more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
Pcode     LogId    ExtDate
------------------------------
p123      2        2021-01-02
p342      3        2021-01-16
p456      4        2021-05-02
p456      5        2021-07-26
p634      6        2021-05-02
p764      7        2021-01-18
p764      8        2021-06-25
```

I am looking for a query which returns only those rows with column one value exists more than one.

So the output should be like this. Which means we are taking only items at which the Pcode exists more than once

```
Pcode     LogId    ExtDate
-----------------------------
p456      4        2021-05-02
p456      5        2021-07-26
p764      7        2021-01-18
p764      8        2021-06-25
```

I tried using dense_rank, but I got stuck here... can't move any further

```sql
select 
    pcode,
    LogId,
    extdate,
    rn
from
    (select 
         pcode,
         L.logid,
         extdate,
         dense_rank() over (partition by pcode order by L.extdate desc) rn
     from 
         kip_project_master P
     inner join 
         kip_report_extraction_log L on L.LogId = P.LogId) tbl
```

Comment: Your code joins 2 tables. From which table are your sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below - **[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57e493abcfb395998960eb727ddbe606)**

```
select pcode,logid,extdate from
(
select *,count(pcode) over(partition by pcode) cnt from t1
)A where cnt>1
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe ?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #yourtable
CREATE TABLE #yourtable(
   Pcode   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  ,LogId   INT 
  ,ExtDate DATE 
);
INSERT INTO #yourtable(Pcode,LogId,ExtDate) VALUES
('p123',2,'2021-01-02'),('p342',3,'2021-01-16'),('p456',4,'2021-05-02')
,('p456',5,'2021-07-26'),('p634',6,'2021-05-02'),('p764',7,'2021-01-18')
,('p764',8,'2021-06-25');

WITH cte AS
(
SELECT   Pcode
FROM      #yourtable
GROUP BY Pcode
HAVING   (COUNT(Pcode) > 1) 
)
SELECT   yt.Pcode, yt.LogId, yt.ExtDate
FROM      yourtable yt 
        INNER JOIN
          cte ON yt.Pcode = cte.Pcode
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming another column is unique, just use `exists`:

```
select kpm.*
from kip_project_master kpm
where exists (select 1
              from kip_project_master kpm2
              where kpm2.pcode = kpm.pcode and kpm2.logid <> kpm.logid
             )
order by kpm.pcode, kpm.logid;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(pcode, logid)`, which should make it pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like,

```
select * from yourtable join (select 
pcode,count(1) as cnt from yourtable group by 
pcode having COUNT(1)>1)b on a.pcode=b.pcode
```